# SQL Server (MSSql) not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a problem with selecting data on four Tables.
first is

**Users**

```
id    |    group_id    |    username
1          10                foo
2          10                bar
3          20                barfoo
```

second is

**Groups**

```
id    |    groupname

10          foo
20          bar
```

thrid is

**mapping**

```
group_id    |    user_id    |    permission_id

 10                  1                100
 10                  1                200
 10                  2                100
 20                  3                300
 20                  3                400
```

and finaly

**permissions**

```
id    |    value    | group_id

100          A            10  
200          B            10
300          B            20
400          A            20
```

what i'm trying to do is to select users who have the permission "A" but not the permission "B"
its a kind of plausybility check, because users in the same grop shold have the same permissions, in this case user bar should be the only result. maybe someone has a hint?
Thank you!

Comment: What does your query look like?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following. SELECT users that have a group with permission A but not permission B.  The subqueries are correlated to the outer query against the USERS table.

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS U
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MAPPING M, PERMISSIONS P
    WHERE M.permission_id = P.permission_id
    AND   M.group_id = U.group_id 
    AND   P.value = 'A')
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM MAPPING M, PERMISSIONS P
    WHERE M.permission_id = P.permission_id
    AND   M.group_id = U.group_id 
    AND   P.value = 'B')
```

Comment: Thank you woot. EXISTS and NOT EXISTS seem not to work to solve my problem, the resultset was allways empty, but this is also a good hint. Never tryed this twice in one query before. Thank you.

Comment: Well I must be missing something about your data because this should bring up users that have A but not B.  Possibly my joins aren't exactly right, I'm not sure exactly what you are doing around the user_id and group_id both on the mapping table. If your data is exactly what I see above, then I would expect no rows to return.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than to do that, for example it's possible to count the distinct value of permissions for every user, check for only one distinct value and check that that value is 'A'

```
SELECT   u.id, u.username
FROM     Users u
         INNER JOIN mapping m ON u.id = m.user_id
         INNER JOIN permissions p ON m.permission_id = p.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT p.Value) = 1
   AND   MAX(p.Value) = 'A'
```

Or is possible to retrieve all the users that have the permission 'A' than remove all the users that have another permission

```
SELECT   u.id, u.username
FROM     Users u
         INNER JOIN mapping m ON u.id = m.user_id
         INNER JOIN permissions p ON m.permission_id = p.id
WHERE    p.Value = 'A'
EXCEPT
SELECT   u.id, u.username
FROM     Users u
         INNER JOIN mapping m ON u.id = m.user_id
         INNER JOIN permissions p ON m.permission_id = p.id
WHERE    p.Value <> 'A'
```

Or is possible to do it in other ways.

That said let's check you data schema

```
Users
id | group_id | username

Groups
id | groupname

Mapping
group_id | user_id | permission_id

Permissions
id | value | group_id
```

the permissions are mapped to the groups or to the users?

- if two users in the same group can have different permissions maybe they shouldn't be in the same group, or the group layer is not necessary and can be dropped.
- if the permissions are based on the groups than Mapping should not have the user_id field.

Comment: Hi Serpiton, thank you so much for the hint of using Except showing the differences between two resultsets! I didn't knew this before! Tt made it for me. Great!